# Questions about the different Scopes/Visibilities of variables in a Delphi Unit

Tags: delphi

Lets say i have a Delphi Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)



  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  nummer:Integer;
```

I understood that there is a public interface-section and a private implementation-section.

functions and procedures which are defined in the public-section can be used from ohter units.

functions and procedures which are defined in the private-section can only be used in this unit.

But are variables after `var` in the interface-section global variables? If yes is there a difference to global variables in public?
And what is the difference between variables defined after implementation and the ones under private?

Comment: See [Declarations and Statements, Scope](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Scope).

Comment: I believe when saying `functions and procedures which are defined in the public-section can only be used in this unit.` you meant to say `private-section` right?

Comment: yeah...it is fixed..thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The variables after the var in the interface section will become accessible for use as a global in any unit that 'uses' this unit.
- The vars defined outside of the class will have one value shared across all instances of the class, so changing the variable in one object call will affect the variable for all objects of this class type. If you define the var inside the class definition, then each object will have its own version of the variable.

Comment: but to use global variables in public section from other units you have to 'use' that unit, too...and with class do you mean the unit?

Comment: I think you should first learn a bit more about Delphi, units and classes. The built-in help of Delphi contains the "Delphi language guide". This explains the language quite well, IMO. It can also be found online: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index

Comment: A unit is a source file. It can contain variables, functions, procedures, constants, classes and ther type declarations. A class is a type that can contain methods (i.e. they are in the scope of the class). If these are in the interface section, they can be "seen" from outside. If they are declared in the implementation section, they can't be seen. This is a similar concept as "public" and "private", but it is not the same as the private, protected, public and published sections of a class.